# Systemd crashes after starting uWSGI service

Tags: 15.04, systemd, uwsgi

I recently updated a virtual machine from utopic to vivid 15.04. I used to have an init.d script for my uwsgi which no longer works.

I followed the official documentation to create a uwsgi service daemon with SystemD from here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Systemd.html.

It seems pretty straight forward, however when I run the service I get this error.

```
miruka@*****:~$ sudo systemctl start emperor.uwsgi.service
Job for emperor.uwsgi.service failed. See "systemctl status emperor.uwsgi.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I have no idea why. Anyway, after that, systemctl crashes and it is unusable.

```
sudo systemctl start emperor.uwsgi.service
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

In dmesg I see:

```
[   37.004704] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[  271.733039] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
[  271.733378] systemd[1]: Unit systemd-journald.service entered failed state.
[  271.733441] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service failed.
[  271.733853] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
[  271.734283] systemd[1]: Stopping Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
[  271.735113] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[  271.792164] systemd-journald[1219]: File /run/log/journal/0d99c9801b8b4ec1a3f5942be02a144c/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[  281.300187] systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service watchdog timeout (limit 1min)!
[  281.301408] systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
[  281.301672] systemd[1]: Unit systemd-timesyncd.service entered failed state.
[  281.301718] systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service failed.
[  281.303804] systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
[  281.305369] systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
[  281.330476] systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
[  281.330905] systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
[  281.331007] systemd[1]: Unit systemd-timesyncd.service entered failed state.
[  281.331047] systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service failed.
[  281.333299] systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
[  281.334691] systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
[  281.343251] systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
[  281.343658] systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
```

Restarting fixes the issue but i still am not able to run my service. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the `RuntimeDirectory` directive from `emperor.uwsgi.service` solved the problem for me.  I'm not certain why this fixes it, or if there are any negative ramifications to this change.

Incidentally, by enabling the `emperor.uwsgi.service` I was able to get it to start fine at boot, but stopping it locked up systemd and I had to force my VM to stop (couldn't reboot or halt) and then reboot it.